# windows forms c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Требуется простейшая Windows форма с различными элементами. В интернете я не нашел хороших статьей по данному. В отличии от Delphi, где все готово. Подскажите хорошие ресурсы по данной теме.

Comment: MSDN? Программы-примеры, идущие с Visual Studio?

Comment: С++ не поддерживает Windows Forms, вы что-то путаете. Может, имеете в виду c++-cli, но тогда это не имеет никакого отношения к C++

Comment: `CreateWindowEx` и `ShowWindow` же.

Comment: Как это windows forms не поддерживает ?? Например, в Visual Studio 2010 можно создать приложение Windows Forms.Но только там многое что не понятно, поэтому я просил скинуть какие-либо ресурсы где описывается ручное создание.

Comment: @Dimcheg, хочу вас разочаровать, приложение Windows Forms можно создать только на языке C++-cli, который фундаментально отличается от языка C++

Comment: Как же тогда создавать формы ?

Comment: @Dimcheg, если под формами подразумеваются всякие интерфейсные штуковины, с чекбоксами, пролями ввода, кнопками и тд, то вопрос примерно равнозначен такому: "как мне написать программу на C++?". Либо воспользуйтесь визуальным редактором, которых десятки. Либо пишите руками, начать можно [отсюда](http://www.tdoc.ru/c/programming/win32/win32-dialog-window-ref.html)